# ANCOVA result miss the cofficience of one variable

Tags: r

I have 2 factors in my data. One factor (named "variable") has 3 variables "BF", "SM", "RM", and another factor is hardwood content (continuous). When I run ANCOVA to analyze model value~ variable*hardwood.content, the result is this:

```
Call:
lm(formula = value ~ hardwood.content * variable, data = rn)

Residuals:
Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-58366  -9038  -2095   4851 199967 

Coefficients:
                             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                  30013.5    11157.2   2.690  0.00880 ** 
hardwood.content              -323.4      181.7  -1.780  0.07918 .  
variableSM                  -49410.0    15778.7  -3.131  0.00248 ** 
variableRM                  -24646.5    15778.7  -1.562  0.12249    
hardwood.content:variableSM   1364.3      257.0   5.309 1.08e-06 ***
hardwood.content:variableRM    381.9      257.0   1.486  0.14145    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ?**?0.001 ?*?0.01 ??0.05 ??0.1 ??1

Residual standard error: 29180 on 75 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3989,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3589 
F-statistic: 9.956 on 5 and 75 DF,  p-value: 2.482e-07
```

Why the result do not have the coefficient of variable "BF"?

This is part of my data:

```
hardwood.content  variable  value
    9.24000         BF      79558.824
    18.60000        BF      28611.111
    2.89000         BF      23673.469
    13.72000        BF      16538.462
    9.24000         SM      5000.000
    18.60000        SM      7500.000
    2.89000         SM      5000.000
    13.72000        SM      0.000
    9.24000         RM      6666.667
    18.60000        RM      21785.714
    2.89000         RM      6000.000
    13.72000        RM      0.000
```

Comment: I guess you need `dummy.coef` function.

Comment: Because by default R uses the so-called treatment contrast for unordered factors. The coefficients you have for "variable" indicate the effect of levels SM and RM compared to level BF. You can check and change the contrasts by using `options("contrasts")`. E.g. this link explain how to use contrasts. [link](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-set-the-contrasts-for-your-data-with-r.html)

Comment: @ user3631369, thank you very much. It is very useful!